# Non-blocking bash redirection

Tags: bash, redirection, pipe, named-pipes

Does anyone know how to redirect the output of a program, running from a bash script,  to a named pipe IN NON BLOCKING MODE (having 'O_NONBLOCK' flag set)?

Answer (score 2):

Open it as read-write?

```
mkfifo wormhole
your_program <>./wormhole
```

Comment: Any subsequent program that read the pipe won't receive anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small program called `ftee` that is available in this StackOverflow anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620387/403614

As far as I know (and as far as my research went), there are no "bash only" solutions.